# How do I get rid of the Runtime.MarshalError in SQS URL

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sqs

Trying to add some basic error handling & logging to a working Lambda function. After adding the elements I now receive this error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to marshal response: sqs.Queue(url='https://us-west-2.queue.amazonaws.com/225565555556/Messages') is not JSON serializable",
  "errorType": "Runtime.MarshalError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

My searches on Stack Overflow have led me to believe something needs to be converted to a string object but I don't know where to fix that. Here is the entire function:

```
# Backport print_function for backwards compatibility
from __future__ import print_function
import logging
# Use built-in package for encoding/decoding JSON data
import json
# Module required to work with Boto3 environment variables
import os
# Module provides classes for manipulating date/time
from datetime import datetime
# AWS Python SDK module
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

# Reference function environment variables
QUEUE_NAME = os.environ['QUEUE_NAME']
MAX_QUEUE_MESSAGES = os.environ['MAX_QUEUE_MESSAGES']
DYNAMODB_TABLE = os.environ['DYNAMODB_TABLE']

# Create AWS service resource objects
sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Define function entry point
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    # Use service resource to call API to retrieve SQS queue name
    try:
        queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=QUEUE_NAME)
        logger.info("Got queue '%s' with URL=%s", QUEUE_NAME, queue.url)
    except ClientError as error:
        logger.exception("Couldn't get queue named %s.", QUEUE_NAME)
        raise error
    else:
        return queue
    
    # Print the number of messages waiting in queue for consumer
    print("ApproximateNumberOfMessages:",
          queue.attributes.get('ApproximateNumberOfMessages'))
    # Iterate through message event records
    for message in event['Records']:
        print("Starting your Lambda Function...")
        body = message["body"]
        id = message['messageId']
        print(str(body))

        # Write message to DynamoDB
        table = dynamodb.Table(DYNAMODB_TABLE)
        # Call DDB API to add message item to table variable
        response = table.put_item(
            Item={
                'MessageId':message['messageId'],
                'Body':message['body'],
                'Timestamp':datetime.now().isoformat()
                },
            )
        print("Wrote message to DynamoDB:", json.dumps(response))
```

Answer (score 0):

The resolution to this error was to change the else statement from:

```
 else:
        return queue
```

To:

```
else:
    return str(queue)
```